# php to javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please help me figure out the javaScript/jQuery equivalent of this php code.

```
<?php 
    $from   = 'USD';
    $to     = 'INR';
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';
    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result); 
    $dollarValue = $allData[1];
    echo 'Value of $1 in Indian Rupees is Rs. '.$dollarValue;
```

Comment: $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';

Comment: @Azmatkarim i have manually inputted the url with the variables included into a browser and it works fine

Comment: yes the varable should be like **.....&s='. $from .'&X='. $to;

Comment: It may not be a simple translation - for starters does Yahoo allow [cross origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to be made?

Comment: hangon i got a solution it can be done @James Thorpe

Comment: I have post my answer

Comment: @Azmatkarim I'm not saying it can't be done, but there's a lot more to consider than just "convert this PHP to JavaScript".

Comment: @James Thrope See Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

You can use jquery ajax to pass values to php page and get output from ajax success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {from:from,to:to}, 
    success:  function(data){
alert(data);
//you can get output form ajax.php, what you expected.
}
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php 
    $from   = $_POST['from'];
    $to     = $_POST['to'];
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';
    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result); 
    $dollarValue = $allData[1];
    echo 'Value of $1 in Indian Rupees is Rs. '.$dollarValue;
```

Ref:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of fopen in this context would be like doing an jQuery Ajax GET request, however since finance.yahoo.com is on a different domain and their server doesn't allow cross domain requests, the GET request would error. To get around this, you'd need to have the PHP script on the same domain and do a request to that.

Answer (score 0):

Save Script on Server

parse.php

```
<?php 


$response =array('result'=>'failed','message'=>'missing params');

if(isset($_GET['from']) && isset($_GET['to'])){
    $from   = $_GET['from'];
    $to     = $_GET['to'];
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from .'&X='. $to;
    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result); 
    $dollarValue = $allData[1];
    $response['result']=$dollarValue;
    $response['message']="value sent";

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

JavaScript method

```
function getData(from,to){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
            xhr1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
         //path to your script
        xhr1.open("GET", "http://localhost/practice/parse.php?from="+from+"&to="+to, true);
        xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr1.send();
        xhr1.onreadystatechange = display_data;
        function display_data() {
            if (xhr1.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr1.responseText);
            //do what you want to do here
            }
}

}
```